# Unable to pull changes in Prod after commiting and pushing from local

Tags: git, github, git-push, git-pull

I see this is asked and answered many times but I believe to be following all the right steps.

1. Git local and remote are already linked and working fine.
2. Branch is Origin Master on both local and remote
3. I did a little change in local files.
4. Committed on Stage local.
5. Did a git push origin master from local which was success and showed that the file is updated.
6. Then logged into remote (Ubuntu) and on Master branch - did a git pull origin master
7. Here is the problem
   [Nothing to update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJtD8.png)
8. Additionally, logged into Github and checked if my commits from local were pushed and they are indeed. See these in Github as well.

Not sure why the git master branch on production is not seeing this changes.. Any insights will be really helpful. Tried few different things looking at other threads but nothing helped. Thanks so much!!

Comment: are you sure you're running `git pull origin master` on the remote server?

Comment: `git pull origin master` shouldnt display this error. Are you sure?

Comment: Hey thanks. Yes, definitely this is from the remote EC2 instance..